# phpmyadmin not loading png(images) nginx

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

After password protecting phpmyadmin directory . png and images are not loading on webpage. Here is my nginx conf:

```
location ^~ /phpmyadmin/ {
    auth_basic            "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two `location` blocks, one for the PHP scripts and one for the assets. This is best achieved using a nested `location` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

```
location ^~ /phpmyadmin/ {
    auth_basic            "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```